# How to Convert tensorflow saved_model to frozen inference graph?

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I train a model by tensorflow 2 to detecting vehicles, but I want to Convert tensorflow saved_model to frozen inference graph.
Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the recommended way to save your model and i would suggest you use saved model.
People around here can help if you explain why you want to use frozen graph specifically and saved model won't help.

If you still want to try freezing you can use [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/981d819e60a294c5c286f8509b1c70b3ac57798f/tensorflow/cc/tools/freeze_saved_model.cc#L278) internal method to do so.